# CMake failed to link static CUDA library

Tags: cmake, cuda

I create a static library following an Nvidia [example](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/building-cuda-applications-cmake/)

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE CACHE BOOL  "")

set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc" CACHE FILEPATH  "")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER  "/opt/qos2.1.1-build4288/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-gcc" CACHE FILEPATH  "")

project(cmake_and_cuda LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)

add_library(particles STATIC
  randomize.cpp
  randomize.h
  particle.cu
  particle.h
  v3.cu
  v3.h
  calc.h
  calc.cu
  )

target_link_libraries(particles PRIVATE stdc++)
set_target_properties(particles PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CUDA)
set_target_properties(particles PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CUDA)

target_compile_options(particles PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>: "--std=c++11" >)

set_target_properties(particles PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

# build executable
add_executable(particle_test main.cpp)
set_target_properties(particle_test PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)
set_target_properties(particle_test PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_link_libraries(particle_test PRIVATE particles)
```

The build is successful. Here is the build log:

```
jenkins@ubuntu:~/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build$ make
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu -B/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build/CMakeFiles /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/particles.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/particles.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
cd /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build/CMakeFiles/particles.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target particles
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/particles.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/particles.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/particles.dir/randomize.cpp.o
/opt/qos2.1.1-build4288/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/ntoaarch64-g++     -o CMakeFiles/particles.dir/randomize.cpp.o -c /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/randomize.cpp
[ 25%] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/particles.dir/particle.cu.o
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -ccbin=/opt/qos2.1.1-build4288/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-gcc   --std=c++11 -x cu -dc /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/particle.cu -o CMakeFiles/particles.dir/particle.cu.o
[ 37%] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/particles.dir/v3.cu.o
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -ccbin=/opt/qos2.1.1-build4288/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-gcc   --std=c++11 -x cu -dc /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/v3.cu -o CMakeFiles/particles.dir/v3.cu.o
[ 50%] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/particles.dir/calc.cu.o
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -ccbin=/opt/qos2.1.1-build4288/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-gcc   --std=c++11 -x cu -dc /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/calc.cu -o CMakeFiles/particles.dir/calc.cu.o
[ 62%] Linking CUDA static library libparticles.a
/usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/particles.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/particles.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar qc libparticles.a  CMakeFiles/particles.dir/randomize.cpp.o CMakeFiles/particles.dir/particle.cu.o CMakeFiles/particles.dir/v3.cu.o CMakeFiles/particles.dir/calc.cu.o
/usr/bin/ranlib libparticles.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
[ 62%] Built target particles
make -f CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
cd /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build/CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target particle_test
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/main.cpp.o
/opt/qos2.1.1-build4288/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/ntoaarch64-g++     -o CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/main.cpp
[ 87%] Linking CUDA device code CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/cmake_device_link.o
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/dlink.txt --verbose=1
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -ccbin=/opt/qos2.1.1-build4288/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-gcc   -Xcompiler=-fPIC -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -shared -dlink CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/main.cpp.o -o CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/cmake_device_link.o  -L/usr/local/cuda/targets/aarch64-qnx/lib/stubs  -L/usr/local/cuda/targets/aarch64-qnx/lib libparticles.a 
[100%] Linking CXX executable particle_test
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/opt/qos2.1.1-build4288/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/ntoaarch64-g++     CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/cmake_device_link.o  -o particle_test  -L/usr/local/cuda/targets/aarch64-qnx/lib/stubs  -L/usr/local/cuda/targets/aarch64-qnx/lib libparticles.a -lstdc++ -lcudadevrt -lcudart_static 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
[100%] Built target particle_test
```

However, if I want to export `libparticles.a` and uses it in another project, it does not work.

```
target_link_libraries(another_project PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libparticles.a)
```

The error log:

```
jenkins@ubuntu:~/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build$ make
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu -B/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build/CMakeFiles /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/another_project.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/another_project.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
cd /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build /home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build/CMakeFiles/another_project.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target another_project
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/another_project.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable particle_test
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/another_project.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/opt/qos2.1.1-build4288/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/ntoaarch64-g++     CMakeFiles/another_project.dir/main.cpp.o  -o another_project ../libparticles.a 
../libparticles.a(calc.cu.o): In function `calc::calc_func()':
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `cudaGetLastError'
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `cudaGetErrorString'
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x104): undefined reference to `cudaDeviceSynchronize'
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x108): undefined reference to `cudaGetLastError'
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `cudaGetErrorString'
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `cudaDeviceSynchronize'
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x164): undefined reference to `cudaGetLastError'
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x17c): undefined reference to `cudaGetErrorString'
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x210): undefined reference to `__cudaPushCallConfiguration'
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x22c): undefined reference to `cudaGetLastError'
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x244): undefined reference to `cudaGetErrorString'
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x25c): undefined reference to `cudaDeviceSynchronize'
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x294): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
../libparticles.a(calc.cu.o): In function `__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil()':
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x480): undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'
../libparticles.a(calc.cu.o): In function `__nv_init_managed_rt_with_module(void**)':
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x4a0): undefined reference to `__cudaInitModule'
../libparticles.a(calc.cu.o): In function `__device_stub__Z16advanceParticlesfP8particlei(float, particle*, int)':
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x5bc): undefined reference to `__cudaPopCallConfiguration'
../libparticles.a(calc.cu.o): In function `__nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback(void**)':
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x708): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFunction'
../libparticles.a(calc.cu.o): In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x744): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft_00036041_00000000_6_calc_cpp1_ii_78a77cc9'
../libparticles.a(calc.cu.o): In function `cudaError cudaMalloc<particle>(particle**, unsigned long)':
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x76c): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
../libparticles.a(calc.cu.o): In function `cudaError cudaLaunchKernel<char>(char const*, dim3, dim3, void**, unsigned long, CUstream_st*)':
tmpxft_00036041_00000000-5_calc.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x7e8): undefined reference to `cudaLaunchKernel'
../libparticles.a(particle.cu.o): In function `__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil()':
tmpxft_00035ff9_00000000-5_particle.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1c4): undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'
../libparticles.a(particle.cu.o): In function `__nv_init_managed_rt_with_module(void**)':
tmpxft_00035ff9_00000000-5_particle.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1e4): undefined reference to `__cudaInitModule'
../libparticles.a(particle.cu.o): In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
tmpxft_00035ff9_00000000-5_particle.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x24c): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_43_tmpxft_00035ff9_00000000_6_particle_cpp1_ii_bd5b23a5'
../libparticles.a(v3.cu.o): In function `__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil()':
tmpxft_00036017_00000000-5_v3.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x3ac): undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'
../libparticles.a(v3.cu.o): In function `__nv_init_managed_rt_with_module(void**)':
tmpxft_00036017_00000000-5_v3.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x3cc): undefined reference to `__cudaInitModule'
../libparticles.a(v3.cu.o): In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
tmpxft_00036017_00000000-5_v3.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x434): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_37_tmpxft_00036017_00000000_6_v3_cpp1_ii_ec982148'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/particle_test.dir/build.make:98: recipe for target 'another_project' failed
make[2]: *** [particle_test] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:70: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/another_project.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/another_project.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jenkins/git_repos/test/test_gpu/build'
Makefile:86: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I cannot understand the reason. In the end, I want to send `libparticles.a` to another developer and let him use it. Any help is really appreciated since I stuck at this problem for a while now.

Comment: yes, you need to link the `libcudart` to your `another_project`.  But you haven't even provided the Cmakelists.txt for that case.

Answer (score 1):

Its about how GCC links library, if the name of lib is `particles` try this

```
target_link_directories(another_project PRIVATE /home/path_to_dir_containing_lib_a_file)
target_link_libraries(another_project PRIVATE particles)
```

Please see this manual:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

```
-l library

    Search the library named library when linking. (The second alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX compliance and is not recommended.)

    The -l option is passed directly to the linker by GCC. Refer to your linker documentation for exact details. The general description below applies to the GNU linker.

    The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library. The directories searched include several standard system directories plus any that you specify with -L.
```

It means that dirs containing libraries are passed separatly (under another flag) from library name

Comment: No it is not about the library path. From the log, I can see that in the first case, there is an aditional command to create the CUDA device linker, but in the 2nd case, there is not